# Cancel Xcode update installation after deleting app

Tags: xcode, app-store, macos-big-sur

I'm in desperate need of some help, I tried to update to the latest version of Xcode (12.5.1), after 20 minutes I noticed it said `Downloading 1.09GB of 1.09GB`.

after 2 hours it still said it was downloading, so I assumed it was stuck.

I tried to stop the update through the App Store by clicking the stop button and nothing happened

so I figured if it's just downloading it can't hurt to delete it, dragged it into the trash bin and emptied the bin.

it was at this point the launch pad updated to say it was now `Installing 1.09GB of 1.09GB` (although, I'm now starting to doubt it actually said downloading in the first place - Dyslexia - )

anyway, now I'm kind of stuck, I can't seem to stop the update, but the update won't continue.

Can anyone help me with this because reddit is telling me to wipe the MacBook clean and use a fresh install (which is NOT ideal)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, If this issue should arise for anyone in the future:

When you delete Xcode during the installation of an update, macOS will (eventually) recognise that Xcode is missing and re-download the app

also, If you are concerned that Xcode's installation has stopped you can actually check the progress of the installation by opening `Console`, clicking on your Mac in the sidebar and typing `appstore` into the search bar.

scroll to the bottom and you will see a second-by-second report of the installation and the estimated time remaining.

For me, at about 95% it seemed to stop, the progress was not changing, but after about an hour the progress began to tick up again so I assume it was a big file

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this same problem while attempting to install XCode 13 running MacOS Big Sur 11.6. I fixed it with these steps:

1. Cancel the App Store install (click the progress circle)
2. Uninstall XCode 12 (drag it to the trash bin)
3. Update mac OS to very latest
4. Re-Initiate install from App Store of XCode 13
5. Wait 8 hours - last 25% of completion takes the longest

Comment: I can’t actually seem to get enough disk space to install Xcode 13 

Comment: but i don't want to update my osx.... is there any other solution?